# JS reset nested property object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue3 composition API and tried resetting the form with the help of Object.assign. Unfortunately, it doesn't reset the form when there are nested properties.

```
const initialForm = {
    name: "",
    details: {
        type: ""
    }
};

const form = reactive({ ...initialForm });

const resetForm = () => {
    Object.assign(form, initialForm);
}
```

Here name is reset but details.type is not reset. What should be the approach to reset form here?

Answer (score 1):

spread operator `...` and `Object.assign` they do shallow copy ONLY.

which means it does not change nested refernces. so `details.type` from `initialForm` is the same used in `form.details.type`.

for that you need to deep copy / clone the object when assigning to `form`. also when you do the `resetForm`.

using https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

```
const initialForm = {
    name: "",
    details: {
        type: ""
    }
};

let form = reactive( _.cloneDeep(initialForm));

const resetForm = () => {
    form =  _.cloneDeep(initialForm) ;
}
```

without external package:

```
const initialForm = {
    name: "",
    details: {
        type: ""
    }
};

let form = {...initialForm, details : {...initialForm.details} } ;

const resetForm = () => {
    form = {...initialForm, details : {...initialForm.details} } ;
}
```